# sql-mysql console with glitches

Tags: sql-interactive-mode

When I run `sql-mysql`, it gives me an unusable console:
[image]

Note how the commands and results are misplaced. My emacs version is 24.5.1.

Comment: Does this happen when you start with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Yep, it happens

Comment: I think this might be documented with a couple of fixes floating around. Check out the Miscellaneous Settings section here: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlMode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is an incompatibility with the MariaDB console. You need to change the mysql regex stored in `sql-product-alist` variable to `\\(?:mysql\\|mariadb\\).*>` to make it compatible with MariaDB.

(I'm not experienced with elisp and couldn't write a command to do that automatically, so instead I just overrode the variable in my init.el. If anyone knows a practical command for that please let me know.)

Comment: (defun sqli-add-hooks ()
  "My hooks for sql-interactive-mode"
  (sql-set-product-feature 'mysql :prompt-regexp "^\\(?:mysql\\|mariadb\\).*> "))


(add-hook 'sql-interactive-mode-hook 'sqli-add-hooks)